# How to return SQL Database Status in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to return MS SQL server Database Status

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474897/track-database-status-change-sql-server

Comment: You can look at the methods to determine the status of a SQL Server database http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1477/methods-to-determine-the-status-of-a-sql-server-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run this

```
SELECT name,state_desc DatabaseStatus_sysDatabase
FROM sys.databases
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query in SQL

```
SELECT Name, state_desc FROM sys.databases
```